# How can I make this pop-up window

Tags: wpf

I would like to know. How can I make this pop-up window?
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/43/wizardpage31zoom84.jpg/

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) class for that.